# Apt repository within Sonatype Nexus 3

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, apt

Trying to use Nexus 3.15.2 as a local/offline package manager. Npm and Maven repos are OK. But, also want to use as an APT repository. It has yum repository feature but not apt repository type. Tried to use nexus-repository-apt plugin with docker container by following these instructions https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apt, but i could not make it.

Nexus Version: Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.15.2-01

Nexus Apt Repository Plugin: nexus-repository-apt-1.0.10

What I'm missing?

Comment: Please add more information about what went wrong.

Comment: What kind of information missin?

Comment: "Tried <whatever manual> but could not make it" is telling us absolutely nothing about what you did, what where the errors you got, how you tried to solve them and where you finally got stuck (compiling plugin, installing, running... ?). So we basically cannot help you. I installed the plugin successfully with the exact same versions you are reporting (as well as with latest nexus version) and the guys managing our virtualization platform are currently using nexus/apt for tests. At first glance, I didn't like having to register a private gpg key inside nexus to create a hosted apt repo...

Comment: Well, I'm gonna give more detail. I'm using Nexus 3.5.12 as a local repository for my npm and mvn packages as a docker container. I build a plugin jar as the link said. Then I tried to put that .jar bundle into the given path inside the container but, there is no such a folder and could not install it via bundle. And I could not find any further detail how I could put this plugin jar file into the container.

Comment: Did you notice there is a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apt/blob/master/Dockerfile) on the plugin repo to build a nexus image with the plugin integrated ? You can use it or adapt to your own needs.

Comment: Yeah, right. Default Dockerfile does not work for me. I made some changes on it and then build the image. Now, i got other issues and trying to solve.

Comment: I sure you should try to use Raw repositories (and repository proxy). It works for Alpine (apk) for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions given in the link, but this time used version 3.16 instead of 3.15. I even created the image and run it successfully, and created Apt repository and upload packages finally. Do not know why it forbids me to upload apt packages even if I could make the container running in version 3.15. Anyway, works fine with the version 3.16.